# How to make only vertical scroll view?

Tags: three20, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I already read this one:

```
http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_scroll_view.php
```

But it seems like there is no property for vertical scroll only. However based on the:

```
http://three20.info/gallery
```

There are few apps that has "vertical-scroll-only" apps, like the facebook apps. In the facebook app, you can keep vertically scroll to view the latest status/posts/images from your friends, I was wondering if they use TTScrollview or UIScrollview.

Whats the correct way of displaying the "vertical-scroll-only" view in Three20 framework?

Please advise, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is most likely using `TTTableView` for displaying the status updates view in the Facebook app.

`TTTableView` inherits `UITableView`, which only scrolls vertically.

Whether you're using Three20 or not, a simple way to implement a vertical only scroll view is to use `UIScrollView`.

To make a `UIScrollView` "vertical-scroll-only" you would set the width of the `contentSize` property to less than or equal to the width of your scroll view, while its height needs to be greater than your scroll view's height to allow for vertical scrolling.

```
UIScrollView *yourScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 210); // <-- sets the scrollable area
yourScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:yourScrollView];
```